# .htaccess rewrite not working?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Instead of having a URL that looks like this:
**www.website.com/developer.php?u=username**

I have attempted to make the URL:
**www.website.com/developer/username**
with the following code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Change developer URL
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ developer.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ developer.php?u=$1
```

However when I type in the second URL, I get a 500 internal error stating that `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

---

I have some other .htaccess rewrite rules that remove the .php / html (ETC) extensions from URLs and also make the index.php file of a directory display when the directory is reached (e.g *www.website.com/directory*) as opposed to *www.website.com/directory.index.php*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^developer/([^/]*)$ /developer.php?u=$1 [L]
```

It will give you:

`www.website.com/developer/username`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase

//Change URL
RewriteRule ^developer/(.+)$ developer.php?u=$1 [R,L]
```